# Renew access token at back-end when ajax call fails

Tags: c#, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app and we use AngularJS to get data from MVC controllers (not ApiControllers). Its authentication is linked to Azure AD using cookie authentication with the default expiry of after 1 hour.

The app is an SPA. Once the user logs in they do not navigate to other pages but use ajax ($http) calls only.

So far, we extended the RedirectToIdentityProvider method in Startup.Configuration() to recognize ajax calls and return error 403 to the client-side when token expired. This way, we avoid redirecting to the authority page and get CORS error.

Further, we implemented persistent token cache helper `TokenCache` (namespace `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`) in `AuthorizationCodeReceived` of the same class.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = ConfigurationHelper.ClientId,
        Authority = ConfigurationHelper.AzureAdAuthorizationUri,

        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true
        },

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
            {
                var code = context.Code;

                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationHelper.ClientId, ConfigurationHelper.AppKey);
                String UserObjectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigurationHelper.AzureAdAuthorizationUri, new InMemoryTokenCache(UserObjectId));

                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, ConfigurationHelper.AzureAdGraphResourceUri);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },


            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // for web API only!
                    context.Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
                    context.State = NotificationResultState.HandledResponse;
                }
                else
                {
                    string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;

                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/" + context.Request.QueryString;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },

            AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
                // Suppress the exception
                context.HandleResponse();

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

- `InMemoryTokenCache` is our wrapper around `TokenCache`
- `IsAjaxRequest` is a function which recognizes an ajax call. All the rest is standard from the ASP.NET MVC 5 template.

Our issue is that when the user access token expires, we want to refresh it and keep going without redirecting the user to a login screen or returning 403 to the client-side. Where and how should we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to refresh the token a few moments before it expires.
In my case, my application is composed of many single pages served by a Node.js server.
After login, I store `token.expires_in` value in a cookie, accessible on server-side.

When user navigate or hit F5 to refresh page, then server initialize client context with `tokenExpiresIn`.
If token expires after 100 minutes, it is automatically refreshed after 90 minutes.

**Sample code**

```
angular.module('app').run(function() {
    
    var tokenExpiresIn = context['tokenExpiresIn'];
    if (tokenExpiresIn) {
      refreshToken(tokenExpiresIn);
    }

    // Automatically refresh token after a delay
    function refreshToken(delay) {
      $log.debug('Token will be refreshed in ' + delay + ' ms');
      $timeout(function () {
        AuthenticationService.refreshToken().then(
        function (token) {
          // Token refresh successful
          // Broadcast event so that anyone can react if necessary
          $rootScope.$broadcast(AuthenticationService.Events.REFRESH_TOKEN, token);
          // Refresh token again after this one expires
          refreshToken(token.expires_in * 1000 * (90/100);
        }, function (error) {
          // Token is invalid, force logout
          AuthenticationService.logout();
        });
      }, delay);
    }

});
```

**Another wayis to use an authentication interceptor**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('authenticationHTTP401Interceptor', authenticationHTTP401Interceptor)

    // Intercept 401 Unauthorized http response from Backend
    authenticationHTTP401Interceptor.$inject = ['$q'];
    function moAuthenticationHTTP401Interceptor($q) {
        return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
              if (rejection.status === 401 
                && rejection.config.url
                && rejection.config.url.indexOf(context.BACKEND_BASE_URL') === 0
                && rejection.headers("WWW-Authenticate")
                && rejection.headers("WWW-Authenticate").indexOf('error="invalid_token"') !== -1
                && rejection.headers("WWW-Authenticate").indexOf('error_description="The access token expired"') !== -1
              )
              // Or using a RegExp
              // if (rejection.status === 401 
              //    && /invalid_token.*The access token  expired/.test(rejection.headers("WWW-Authenticate"))
              // )  
              {
                // Refresh token here
                // Display an overlay while doing it if necessary
              }
              return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }
```

Source : [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3)

Comment: This is an option but the theory says I should not do that. Refresh tokens are only for getting an access token and only if a user requests something after the later expires.

Comment: I've added another solution, hope it helps ;)